# Find the last two digits of $7^{100}-3^{100}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the last two digits of $7^{100}-3^{100}$

From Euler's theorem one gets that $\phi(100) = 40 \Rightarrow 7^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}, 3^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}.$

I couldn't really work this out without using a calculator to compute the powers. How can I continue from here? I could write the expressions as $7^{100} \equiv 7^{40}\cdot7^{60} \equiv 7^{60} \pmod{100}$, but I would still need to deal with the $7^{60}...$

Comment: One thing I would try is compute some powers of $7$ and see if I get a cycle modulo $100$ and then reduce.

Comment: You know $7^{40}$ is $1$, so $7^{80}$ is also $1$. Compute $7^{20}$ by hand (squaring $7^{10}$), all mod $100$, and you're done.

Comment: What Alvin Lepik commented above.  Specifically, what is $7^4 \pmod{100}?$

Comment: Continuing my comment with a **hint**: $3^4 = (8\times 10) + 1 \Rightarrow 3^{(4n)} = \left(3^4\right)^n \equiv \binom{n}{1}[(8\times 10)^1] + 1 \pmod{100}.$  Therefore, with $\binom{n}{1} = n,$ look for a small $n$ such that $(n \times 8 \times 10) \equiv 0 \pmod{100}.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, notice:$$(10-3)^{100}-3^{100} = \sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{100}{k}10^{100-k}(-3)^k \equiv0 \pmod {100}$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

The [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $100$ is $20$,

so if $\gcd(a,100)=1$ then $a^{20}\equiv1\bmod100$,

so $a^{100}=(a^{20})^5\equiv1\bmod 100$.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Calculate $7^{100}-3^{100}$ separately for modulo $5^2$ and $2^2$.Then,combine them using chinese remainder theorem.It will be easier to calculate I think

Answer (score 1):

Yet an other answer, that leads to the result (without using the Euler indicator function). Explicit computations.

- Working modulo $4$, i.e. in $\Bbb Z/4$, we have $7^{100}-3^{100}=3^{100}-3^{100}=0$.
- Working modulo $25$, i.e. in $\Bbb Z/25$, note that $1/7=18$ (because of $7\cdot 18=126=1$), so we have $18^{100}(7^{100}-3^{100})=1-54^{100}=1-4^{100}=1-1024^{20}=1-(-1)^{20}=1-1=0$.

So $(7^{100}-3^{100})$ is zero modulo $4$, and modulo $25$, so also modulo $4\cdot 25=100$.

Answer (score 0):

For $7$ we have the cycle modulo $100$ with $7, 49, 43, 1$. Then $7^{20}= (7^4)^{5}\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is my try. As being a high school student, I don't have any idea about $\text{mod}$.

$$7^{100}=(10-3)^{100}=\sum_{r=0}^{100} {{100}\choose{r}}(10)^{100-r}(-3)^r$$ Now, since we want only last two digits, we are interested in terms with index of $10$ less than $2$ as other terms will terminate with unnecessary zeroes.

We've to find last two digits of $${100\choose 99}(10)(-3)^{99}+{100\choose 100}(-3)^{100}-3^{100}\\ =(1000)(-3)^{99}$$

Hence, the last two digits are $00$.